# Is it possible to reference a value from an SQL database in a web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is a strange question, basically we are trying to use the web.config file to restrict accesss to certain users. Unfortunately the site isn't using roles but rather accesses an sql database to figure out the user's role based on a stored value. Is it possible to somehow pull the SQL value to determine whether or not a user should be granted access, for example:

```
  <location path="Restrictedpage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="SQL Reference would go here, returning the usernames that fall under certain criteria, such as value admin = 1"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

I know this is a weird question, I am pretty new to all this but I could really use some help, if someone has a better method I would appreciate ideas on that too.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using default ASP.NET database to store users and roles? If so  can use the role `<allow roles="comma-separated list of roles"/>`

Comment: Grab the data in code-behind and check if user is in role?

Comment: This is not my original code I am working on, but I am pretty sure that none of the users have roles assigned to them. I tried <allow roles="Admin"/> and many others to no avail, is there a good way to check whether or not the users are assigned roles?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The web.config is meant for declarative configuration.  With that said, just because there aren't roles in the database, doesn't mean you can't use roles in the application.  For example, if someone has `IsAdmin = 1` in the database, you can put them in the `Administrators` role when they login.  Then, you could easily use the `<authorization>` section in the web.config to only allow members of the `Administrators` role access to that location.

As an alternative to the web.config, you could use the `Page_Load()` of RestrictedPage.aspx to query the database and check if the user is an admin.  If they are not, redirect the user someplace else.  However, if you can re-compile the code and are going to go through all this trouble, you may as well just use a role-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful. Is there an easy way to create roles and assign existing admins to the Admin role?

Comment: That depends on the type of authentication you are using for the web app.  If you are using FormsAuthentication, on the login page, you can store the role name in the UserData of the FormsAuthentication ticket.  Then, in the Application_AuthenticateRequest() event handler in the Global.asax file, you can parse the UserData section to extract the role names.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication provides a good example of this.  Alternately, if you use the membership and role providers, they take care of this for you.  I've done it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

If web.config file is changed, IIS automatically reloads the config. I am not saying that this is the recommended approach. But... You can write a code in your application to modify web.config file if the deny list is updated. Just make sure your application has access to modify Web.config.

Answer (score -1):

You may also consider using membership provider that would allow you to keep your current database schema unchanged http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx.

Tutorial on creating membership provider: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider